# Как сделать авторизацию по колонке name вместо email в laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как сделать авторизацию по колонке name вместо email, email нужно вообще убрать не могу найти метод который отвечает за авторизацию и сравнение подскажите куда копать

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-authenticating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController добавьте

```
public function username()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Так же в  \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController не забудте поменнять валидацию в методе

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
```